# RHEL/CentOS 7 run named-chroot on systemctl named invocation?

Tags: bind, centos7, systemd, chroot, rhel7

How can I make systemd treat calls to `systemctl xx named` as calls to `systemctl xx named-chroot`?

Under RHEL/CentOS 6 installing the `bind-chroot` package would set up a chroot'ed environment for BIND, but the control script would remain the same. i.e. a `service named start` would control the BIND process regardless if it were chroot'ed or not.

I'm migrating DNS servers to RHEL7, where `named` and `named-chroot` are now independent services. This can cause trouble for some operators who are not aware of the distinction and may think that BIND is down if they run `systemctl status named` instead of `systemctl status named-chroot`.

Is there a way to link the `named` control script to `named-chroot` under systemd so as to avoid the risk of confusion?

Comment: Tell your operators to be aware of the difference.

Comment: I can't rely on all of the operators being properly informed, and thus need a foolproof default to prevent issues.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a symbolic link named named-chroot.service in the  /etc/systemd/system directory linking to named.service file?